# Can I pass parameters to my dynamically created classes?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, processing, classloader, urlclassloader

I am successfully loading a class from an external `MyClass.class` file at runtime, and am able to call it's methods assuming I know the name of them, which I do.

The problem I'm having is I cannot figure out how to pass a parameter to the constructor of the class I am loading.

How can I modify this to pass a parameter to `MyClass`'s constructor? Also, how can I access `MyClass`'s public variable: `infoToAccess`?

Here are the files I'm working with. (Keep in mind, ClassLoaderExample.pde was written for Processing, but other than `sketchPath("")` and the lack of a `main` function, it is identical.

#### ClassLoaderExample.pde: The main file that loads the class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.lang.ClassLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/////// FILE STRUCTURE /////
// ClassLoaderExample     //
// --this file            //
// --tmp                  //
// ----MyClass.class      //
////////////////////////////

// TODO
//   Send parameter to MyClass constructor (by reference)
//   Get public int number from MyClass

void setup()
{
    String className = "MyClass";
    Object instance;
    Method updateMethod;

    // sketchPath("") returns the directory this file is in
    File file = new File(sketchPath(""));
    try
    {
        URL url = file.toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

        ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("tmp."+className);

        try
        {
            instance = loadedClass.newInstance();
            updateMethod = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod("update");

            // Calls MyClass's update() method
            try
            {
                updateMethod.invoke(instance);
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {System.out.println(e);}
            catch (IllegalAccessException    e) {System.out.println(e);}
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        catch (NoSuchMethodException  e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException  e) {System.out.println(e);}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}
```

#### MyClass.java: The class I am loading:

```
package tmp;
public class MyClass
{
    public int infoToAccess = 1337;

    public MyClass(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("MyClass constructor was called with numebr: " + i);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        System.out.println("Update was called.");
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: you might want to take a look here

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredmethod.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the class you loaded to get hold of the constructor
you need an use that to create a new instance.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

...

Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("tmp."+className);
try {
  Constructor<?> ctor=loadedClass.getConstructor(int.class);
  ctor.newInstance(42);
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! I incorporated your contribution [here](http://pastebin.com/3yfDH55Z).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use reflection for both of the things you asked about:

```
Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("tmp." + className);
Object oInstance = null;
try {
    Constructor<?> c = loadedClass.getConstructor(Integer.class);
    oInstance = c.newInstance(10);
} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
    //Handle the possibility that you cannot access this constructor
}
```

To access the public field of your object:

```
try {
    Field field = loadedClass.getField("infoToAccess");
    int fieldValue = field.getInt(oInstance);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    //Handle the possibility that you cannot access this field
}
```

Comment: When I implement your solution directly the `getConstructor` line throws the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tmp.MyClass.<init>(java.lang.Integer)` However, if I replace `Integer.class` with `int.class` it works. 

However, the Field example works perfectly. So thanks! I incorporated your contribution [here](http://pastebin.com/3yfDH55Z).

Comment: `int.class` is a new one to me - you learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link I wrote in the comments, you can pass parameters in this call

updateMethod = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod("update", parameters go here);

then you should be able to invoke the method with a parameter(s)

Comment: I think you got downvoted because that's not the exact question I asked, but this was just for me to learn, so I appreciate any new information I can get. So thanks! I incorporated your contribution here: http://pastebin.com/3yfDH55Z

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the name :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass arguments to the constructor you cannot use `getInstance()`, you have to get the constructor object and pass the parameters there.

Example:

```
Constructor constructor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
MyObject myObject = (MyObject) constructor.newInstance("constructor-arg1");
```

See tutorial here: [Java Reflection - Constructors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html)